# Chrome launcher icon right click menu doesn't show option for opening new window

Tags: unity, google-chrome, launcher

I installed google-chrome-stable by following instructions from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome). When I right click on the Chrome launcher icon, It doesn't show options like 'Open a new window' or 'Open icognito window. It just lists the windows I have already open and options to unlock from launcher & to quit it.
Here's my google-chrome.desktop from ~/.local/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Chrome - Google Chrome
Icon=google-chrome
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome %U
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=google-chrome
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Please help me fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you previously have Chrome installed on the same system?

Comment: I had it installed in 14.04, that was working fine. This happened after I did a fresh install of 16.04.

Comment: So no chance on outdated `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: yes, I didn't restore anything from my previous install.

Comment: Not sure what the link in your question is sourced by, but the `.desktop` file is a simplified one, and the file includes a few outdated/deprecated keywords, which are not (anymore) in the recent Chrome versions. The recent version is in the repositories.

Comment: So, should I reinstall it. and can you point a source on how to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved myself by copying the desktop file from /usr/share/applications to ~/.local/share/applications.
`cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: Now I am a bit puzzled; when I asked you *"So no chance on outdated .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications"*, you mentioned that was not the case. If you copy the global one locally, it is quite impossible anything changes, *unless* you overwrite an existing local one.

Comment: I don't know how it happened. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu and then installed chrome, It had been happening since the moment chrome installed.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Google Chrome and reinstall it this way, open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable  
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Now everything should work as expected.

Comment: @cl-netbox Thank you, But it still doesn't work.